# How to find maximal value for function x ∈ L2 ([0, T ])?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The question required me to find the maximal value of the function below at unit ball:
$$|\int_0^Te^{-(T-τ)}x(τ)d(τ)|$$ for function x ∈ $L_2$ ([0,T ]).

I know we can it by the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, but how can we write it in the form of the inequality? Can anyone pls help?

Is it correct if I use **Cauchy-Schwartz inequality** to prove the above function is **continuous**, then it can attain its maximum value at unit ball. After that, since it is continuous, we can say that it obtain **maximum when T=0**?

Comment: What if I need to do it by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality?

Comment: Write y(t)=e^{-(T-t)} and then look at the inner product on L_2.

Comment: Should I write $\overline{y(t)}$= $e^{t-T}$ instead?